# TestNG xml parameters not honored by Test script when I ran all suite classes in one go

Tags: java, xml, testng

I have a `TestNG.xml` as below

```
<test name="Regression Tests - Test1">
    <parameter name="TestData" value = "Sample.xls" />
    <parameter name="VaultName" value = "Test Vault" />
    <parameter name="RestoreVault" value = "Test1" />
    <classes>
        <class name="Project.Tests.RegTest1"/>
        <class name="Project.Tests.RegTest2"/>
     </classes>
</test>
```

My `RegTest1.java` have a @Test method as

```
@Test
@Parameters("sourceName")
public void test1(String sourceName) throws Exception {

}

@Test
@Parameters("VaultName")
public void test2(String VaultName) throws Exception {

}
```

When I ran all suites together, it doesn't recognize the input params `TestData,VaultName` etc and throws an exception as

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'TestData' is required by @Test on method test1 but has not been marked @Optional or defined
```

But, if my suite have only one test class specified it pickups the appropriate parameters passed.

How can I pass parameters while running all suites together?

Comment: Something is missing in your description: where are you using `TestData`? I see `sourceName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you passing "sourceName" in testng.xml??

- test1 method requires parameter by name - sourceName. So it is giving error in test1 method not test2.

And if it is optional parameter, then define test like:

```
public void test1(@Optional("sourceName") String sourceName) { 
    //Your test-case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'Test Data' param. You can probably load it on a BeforeClass annotation and make it null when you don't need it. Like so:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters("TestData")
public void init(String testData) throws Exception {
   testData = null;
}

@Test
@Parameters("sourceName")
public void test1(String sourceName) throws Exception {

}

@Test
@Parameters("VaultName")
public void test2(String VaultName) throws Exception {

}
```